# ViewState and Security Settings generating errors

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have an odd reoccurring error that I believe is related to View State and security settings. This error appears on one of my client’s site between 1 to 6 times a day:

Source: System.Web
Error in: /detail.aspx?CaseID=1852
Error Message: **Unable to validate data.**
Stack Trace:    at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.**EncryptOrDecryptData(**Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, IVType ivType, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString)

Researching online has lead to a deadend. I believe it has do with security and ViewState. Because this is an ecommerce site, I took the extra steps of protecting against a number of treats, includign XSS and CSFR. Here are the steps I took:

- Turned on **HTTPOnly** Cookies (Protects against XSS Style Attacks)
- Turned on **Secure Cookie** Flag (Protects against XSS Style Attacks)
- Created a BasePage which all the pages inherit instead of Page, in the Basepage I overrides OnInit and set **ViewStateUserKey** to SessionID  (Protects against certain CSFR Style Attacks)
- Explicitly enabled validateRequest (On by default, but can be overwritten)
- **ViewState Encryption Enabled**

The website is hosted on a Win2003 Virtual Server, using **ASP.NET 3.5 SP1** and **AJAX**. The page is not using caching, which some articles I found suggested was a problem when you set the ViewStateUserKey key to a unique value, such as SessionID. I can duplicate this exact error if I turn off cookies in my browser and try to view one of the pages that creates the error.

Notes, The error message does NOT mention MAC has failed

Comment: You can try adding a machineKey value to the web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My theory is that those that experience this error are on networks that have a Proxy/Caching Server. My solution was to only set the ViewStateUserKey when it was a secure connection. Most Proxy/Caching Servers are only set to cache HTTP connections, not secure connections.